# How to solve Traveling Salesman in SML?

Tags: algorithm, sml, traveling-salesman

Does anybody have a traveling salesman problem solution in Standard ML, please tell me.

I've tried a lot but am not successful.

Answer (score 5):

The brute force solution to traveling salesman is very straight forward. You populate a list of possible paths and pick the smallest one.

As for doing this in SML there  are a myriad of methods. It will firstly depend on what data structure you are using to do this, and secondly on whether or not you wish to use 'lazy' functions / streams.

My suggestion to you is to code a simple path finder first, then extend it to generating all paths as a list or other data structure. Finally sort that list for the smallest trip length. Use the [TSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) on wiki as a helpful resource when considering how to go about solving this problem.

I'm sorry, but I'm not in the business of doing others homework for them.

Good [SML](http://csus.cs.mcgill.ca/wiki/COMP-302_(Panangaden%2C_Pientka%2C_Winter_06)_Lectures) reference, and [another](http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs302/resources/harper-programming-in-standard-ml.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use 2D arrays in SML. This is an F# solution:

```
let salesman2 (g:int array array) = 
    let n = Array.length g
    let rec salesman' visited last acc = 
        if Set.count visited = n then acc
        else 
            {0..n-1} 
            |> Seq.filter (fun i->not (Set.contains i visited)) 
            |> Seq.map (fun i->salesman' (Set.add i visited) i (acc + g.[last].[i]))
            |> Seq.min
    salesman' Set.empty 0 0 

let g = [|[|0;1;2;4|]; [|1;0;2;2;|]; [|2;2;0;3|]; [|4;2;3;0|] |]
salesman2 g
```

Translating it into SML should be straightforward if you know SML.

Comment: I am pleased that part of my MSc at Uni Of Edinburgh I have forgotten!